# How to launch python from within python Windows 10)?

Tags: python, windows-10

I am running python3 in Windows 10. Within my program, I try to launch another python instance.

```
os.system("python -m http.server")
print("All Done")
```

or

```
os.system("python")
```

I want to see a Window shell that pops up and allow me the see the output and interact with it. But instead the program just continues. I don't even see a window pops up. What am I missing?

Comment: Why would you want to do this instead of importing the other modules you're trying to run?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to open a new window, you need to use `start cmd`

If you want to open a new window running a command from cmd, that's `start cmd /c "command"`

e.g

```
import os
os.system('start cmd /c "python -m http.server"')
```

However, if you really just want to run another python process, you can import and run the server directly from code - [refer docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.server.html)

Comment: It only works for me if I run python from the command prompt. When I run it from IDLE, it didn't work. It returns `0` immediately.

Comment: I dont regularly use IDLE, but it does seem to open the CMD window, just doesn't run the command. You wouldn't use IDLE to run code in a real environment anyway

Comment: Anyways, using `cmd` at all is not portable. Will you always be using Windows? You should really be using the multiprocessing module - https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: I am not sure how multiprocessing module will help me because I still need to launch a separate program (I used `python` but it could just as well be any other program, e.g. `chkdsk`).

Comment: `os.system` (or better `subprocess.Popen`) does that. Why do you need a new CMD window?

Comment: Because the program is interactive.

Comment: Interactive to who? Your python process will open a new subprocess, but you then would be unable to interact with it from Python. That doesn't preclude you from piping input from `subprocess` module, though